# python basic mathematical program using classes

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import random
class Problem:
def _init_(self):
    if self.operation == '+':
        self.answer = operand1 + operand2
    if self.operation == '-':
        self.answer = operand1 - operand2
    if self.operation == '*':
        self.answer = operand1 * operand2
    if self.operation == '/':
        self.answer = operand1 / operand2
    
def getOperand1(self):
    return self.operand1

def getOperand2(self):
    return self.operand2

def getAnswer(self):
    return self.answer

def getOperation(self):
    return self.operation

def _addition(self):
    if getOperation(self) == '+':
        operand1.random.randrange(0, 10)
        operand2.random.randrange(0, 10)

def _subtraction(self):
    if getOperation(self) == '-':
        op2 = operand2.random.randrange(0,10)
        ans = answer.random.randrange(0,10)
        operand1 = ans - op2

def _multiplication(self):
    if getOperation(self) == '*':
        operand1.random.randrange(0, 10)
        operand2.random.randrange(0, 10)

def _division(self):
    if getOperation(self) == '/':
        operand2 != 0
        

def createNewProblem(self):
    orr = operation.random('+', '-', '*', '/')
    if orr == '+':
        _addition(self)
    
    if orr == '-':
        _subtraction(self)
    
    if orr == '*':
        _multiplication(self)
    
    if orr == '/':
        _division(self)

def _str_(self):
    return f'{operand1}{operation}{operand2} = {answer}'

def main():
prob1 = Problem()
print(prob1)
print('Operand1: ', prob1.getOperand1())
print('Operand2: ', prob1.getOperand2())
print('Answer: ', prob1.getAnswer())
print('Operation: ', prob1.getOperation())  
print()

for count in range(25):
    prob1.createNewProblem()
    print(prob1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
main()
```

This is my code which has to perform basic mathematical operations using class in python
I'm getting an error: AttributeError: 'Problem' object has no attribute 'operand1'
Can you help me with this so that this program works!?
some info for the code provided to us:

createNewProblem() which randomly chooses an operation ('+', '-', '*', '/') then calls the appropriate private method to generate the numbers for the problem

four "private" methods (__addition(), __subtraction(), __multiplication(), __division() ) which randomly generate the values for operand1, operand2, and/or the answer for each type of problem. For addition and multiplication, operand1 and operand2 should be random digits 0-10 inclusive. For subtraction, to guarantee a whole number answer, generate operand2 and the answer to be random digits 0-10 inclusive then sum them to determine operand1. Similarly work backward for division to guarantee a whole number answer, but operand2 can't be zero.

The constructor (**int**) has no parameters (except self, of course). It should initialize the instance variables to represent the problem 1 + 1 = 2.

Comment: You never give the object a `operand1` attribute. Also, `def _init_(self)` needs to be `def __init__(self)`.

Comment: The instructions don't seem to mention `getOperand` methods though, or making `operand1`/`operand2` attributes of the class. It says the operands should be generated inside the math methods.

Comment: The whole constructor makes very little sense if you wish to generate the operands randomly. you don't need any of its content, actually.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of things are missing and the indentation is wrong.

To resolve that particular error (`AttributeError: 'Problem' object has no attribute 'operand1'`), you need to create the attributes in the class:

```py
class Problem:
    def __init__(self, operand1, operation, operand2):
        self.operand1 = operand1
        self.operation = operation
        self.operand2 = operand2
```

And to create an instance of the `Problem` class with:

```py
prob1 = Problem(12, '*', 5)
```

You also need to use `__init__` instead of `_init_`, and `__str__` instead of `_str_`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but the guide says "The constructor (int) has no parameters (except self, of course). It should initialize the instance variables to represent the problem 1 + 1 = 2." So is there any other way to represent the problem in the constructor? I have got a lot of questions regarding this can you message me your personal email or anything where I can contact you? Thanks!

Comment: That is not the usual way to do things in python. We can specify default value for the keyword arguments. But a constructor should always ask for all arguments it needs to create an object. Is this home work or self-study? If it is home work, the home work doesn't make sense.

Comment: This is actually an assignment for my college, the guide is provided by the college

Comment: The assignment doesn't make sense. Did you copy the assignment from a blackboard? If that is the case, try to ask your class mate for the correct assignment. If this is the exact wording of the assignment on a printed handout, I would suggest to ask the professor.

Comment: I guess the last sentence of the assignment should be:

The constructor of the Problem class should have default values that represent the problem `1 + 1 = 2`.

While `The constructor (int) has no parameters (except self, of course).` is true, this sentence probably is not part of the assignment

Answer (score 0):

```py
import random


class Problem:
    def __init__(self, operand1=1, operation='+', operand2=1):
        # ------------------------------------- #
        # -- Guard against invalid arguments -- #
        # ------------------------------------- #
        if operation not in ["+", "-", "*", "/"]:
            raise ValueError(f"Invalid operation: {operation}")
        if not isinstance(operand1, int):
            raise ValueError(f"Invalid operand1: {operand1}. It should be an "
                             f"int.")
        if not isinstance(operand2, int):
            raise ValueError(f"Invalid operand2: {operand2}. It should be an "
                             f"int.")
        if operation == "/" and operand2 == 0:
            raise ValueError(f"Invalid problem: {self}. Division by zero is "
                             f"not allowed.")
        # --------------------------------------------------- #
        # -- Copy the arguments as attributes of the class -- #
        # --------------------------------------------------- #
        self.operand1 = operand1
        self.operation = operation
        self.operand2 = operand2
        # -------------------------- #
        # -- Calculate the answer -- #
        # -------------------------- #
        # Since we have checked the arguments, eval here should not raise an
        # error.
        self.answer = eval("%s%s%s" % (operand1, operation, operand2))

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.operand1} {self.operation} {self.operand2} = " \
               f"{self.answer}"

    def make_new_problem(self):
        # Erh. This doesn't make sense. Why do we need this method?
        # If I want a random new problem, I would directly call
        #     make_rand_problem().
        # If I want to create a specific problem, I would use the constructor
        #     of this class.
        # Name of a method should be all lower case. See
        # https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id47
        return make_rand_problem()


def make_rand_problem():
    """Make random problem
    This function ensures that the answer of the problem is a whole number.
    No division by zero would occur.
    """
    problem_list = [
        _make_addition_problem(),
        _make_subtraction_problem(),
        _make_multiplication_problem(),
        _make_division_problem()
    ]
    return random.choice(problem_list)


def _make_two_rand_int():
    x = random.randrange(0, 10)
    y = random.randrange(0, 10)
    return x, y


def _make_addition_problem():
    x, y = _make_two_rand_int()
    return Problem(x, '+', y)


def _make_multiplication_problem():
    x, y = _make_two_rand_int()
    return Problem(x, '*', y)


def _make_subtraction_problem():
    operand2, answer = _make_two_rand_int()
    operand1 = answer + operand2
    assert operand1 - operand2 == answer
    p = Problem(operand1, '-', operand2)
    assert p.answer == answer
    return p


def _make_division_problem():
    operand2 = random.randrange(1, 10)
    answer = random.randrange(0, 10)
    operand1 = answer * operand2
    assert int(operand1 / operand2) == answer
    p = Problem(operand1, '/', operand2)
    # Assert the answer of the problem is same as
    # the answer that we expected.
    assert p.answer == answer
    return p


def main():
    p1 = Problem()
    print(p1)
    # No need to make getters for attributes that are not "private"
    print('Operand1: ', p1.operand1)
    print('Operand2: ', p1.operand2)
    print('Answer: ', p1.answer)
    print('Operation: ', p1.operation)
    print(p1)

    for count in range(25):
        p2 = make_rand_problem()
        print(p2)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: If you copy this, the grader will definitely know you didn't write this. This answer contains many things that you haven't learned from the class. Please study this and write your own answer.

Comment: This program works now ... Check and make sure it fits your assignment after you get the correct assignment.